# Pass Value from jQuery AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say I have this script for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdata() {
        var referenceNumber = $("#reference_number").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'getlistofsomething.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'referenceNumber=' + referenceNumber,
            success: function (output_string) {
                $("#name").val(output_string[0]);
                $("#address").val(output_string[1]);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way I can pass the value in `$("#address").val(output_string[1]);` into the PHP file this script above is in?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: your `output_string[1]` is already coming from your server, so why do you need to send it over there again? If you need to send it to another script, you can simply take out the value again with `$("#address").val()` and POST that to another URL.

Comment: Isn't that where the value came from?

Comment: the value is coming from already from php file and then after you are adding it to address id....? elaborate it in deeply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just to send it to the server using `GET`.  Only do this if the data isn't very sensitive...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata()
    {
        var referenceNumber = $("#reference_number").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getlistofsomething.php?address=' + $("#address").val(output_string[1]),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'referenceNumber='+referenceNumber,
            success: function(output_string)
                {                               
                    $("#name").val(output_string[0]);
                    $("#address").val(output_string[1]);
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This can then be accessed in your php script with:

```
$address = $_GET['address'];
```